# Binary Bomb Phase 4 - Can't figure it out

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

Please Help, I have looked all over, and I just can't seem to find anything.

```
    Dump of assembler code for function phase_4:
   0x08048d81 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048d82 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048d84 <+3>: sub    $0x28,%esp
   0x08048d87 <+6>: lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048d8a <+9>: mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048d8e <+13>:    movl   $0x8049a68,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048d96 <+21>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048d99 <+24>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048d9c <+27>:    call   0x8048788 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x08048da1 <+32>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
   0x08048da4 <+35>:    jne    0x8048dac <phase_4+43>
   0x08048da6 <+37>:    cmpl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x08048daa <+41>:    jg     0x8048db1 <phase_4+48>
   0x08048dac <+43>:    call   0x8049236 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048db1 <+48>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048db4 <+51>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048db7 <+54>:    call   0x8048b50 <func4>
   0x08048dbc <+59>:    cmp    $0x262,%eax
   0x08048dc1 <+64>:    je     0x8048dc8 <phase_4+71>
   0x08048dc3 <+66>:    call   0x8049236 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048dc8 <+71>:    leave  
   0x08048dc9 <+72>:    ret   






 Dump of assembler code for function func4:
   0x08048b50 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048b51 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048b53 <+3>: sub    $0x18,%esp
   0x08048b56 <+6>: mov    %ebx,-0x8(%ebp)
   0x08048b59 <+9>: mov    %esi,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x08048b5c <+12>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%ebx
   0x08048b5f <+15>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x08048b64 <+20>:    cmp    $0x1,%ebx
   0x08048b67 <+23>:    jle    0x8048b83 <func4+51>
   0x08048b69 <+25>:    lea    -0x1(%ebx),%eax
   0x08048b6c <+28>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048b6f <+31>:    call   0x8048b50 <func4>
   0x08048b74 <+36>:    mov    %eax,%esi
   0x08048b76 <+38>:    sub    $0x2,%ebx
   0x08048b79 <+41>:    mov    %ebx,(%esp)
   0x08048b7c <+44>:    call   0x8048b50 <func4>
   0x08048b81 <+49>:    add    %esi,%eax
   0x08048b83 <+51>:    mov    -0x8(%ebp),%ebx
   0x08048b86 <+54>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%esi
   0x08048b89 <+57>:    mov    %ebp,%esp
   0x08048b8b <+59>:    pop    %ebp
   0x08048b8c <+60>:    ret
```

I've been thinking that there are two numbers and that one of them is 610 since    0x08048dbc <+59>:    cmp    $0x262,%eax which 0x262 is 610.

Comment: Need a little more information about what you think is going on and what this is supposed to do... As it is, this isn't really a "question".

Comment: You should probably step through this to see what is actually going on using GDB.  Usually the point of this assignment is to become very efficient at using a debugger.

Comment: Well I figured that there is two numbers it wants. I can get down to the last test where it compares me to the last explode bomb, but it keeps exploding. When I use 1 and 610 it seems to get that far, but I can't seem to pass that last test

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the format string passed to `sscanf` you will most likely see a single `%d` directive. Line `+32` checks that `sscanf` read exactly 1 number, otherwise the bomb will explode.

Line `+59` is checking the return value of `func4` against `610`, so you need to figure out what number to feed `func4` such that it will give `610` back.

Without giving too much away, let me tell you that `func4` is a simple recursive implementation of a well-known sequence. You should be able to find the recursion formula from the assembly code, and then you will probably recognize it.